# Independent t test significant but post-hoc planned analysis not

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, multiple-comparisons, planned-comparisons-test

I was analysing two sets of data. In most cases for the study post hoc planned comparisons identified significance (<0.05), however for one sample, this was not achieved. However an independent t test did report significance. Does this happen? Do post hoc planned comparisons require a greater degree of variation to achieve significance?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by a "post-hoc planned comparison" and how it is different from the t-tests you ran? Were these assessing separate endpoints? Comparing other groups?

Comment: Was the post-hoc comparison done using some family-wise correct for multiple comparisons? If so, that would explain the difference. Hypothetically, assuming you did 10 planned post-hoc comparisons but the method you used accounted for multiple comparisons, in order to maintain a family-wise 95% test over the family of 10 tests, each individual test needs to be somewhat more stringent than 0.05 as a cutoff.. As @AdamO says, some more details on how the post-hoc comparison were performed is required to answer rather than speculate.